# C++ error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'I2Cdev' (classname)

Tags: c++, class, include

I am getting this error when trying to add a .h file to my CodeLite project. Here is my file, relatively short:

```
#ifndef _I2CDEV_H_
#define _I2CDEV_H_

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// I2C interface implementation setting
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION       I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE

// comment this out if you are using a non-optimal IDE/implementation setting
// but want the compiler to shut up about it
#define I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION_WARNINGS

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// I2C interface implementation options
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE         1 // Wire object from Arduino

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Arduino-style "Serial.print" debug constant (uncomment to enable)
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//#define I2CDEV_SERIAL_DEBUG

//#include "Arduino.h"
//#include <Wire.h>
///
// 1000ms default read timeout (modify with "I2Cdev::readTimeout = [ms];")
#define I2CDEV_DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT     1000

**class I2Cdev {** //this line has the error
    public:
        I2Cdev();
        
        static int8_t readBit(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint8_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        //static int8_t readBitW(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint16_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        static int8_t readBits(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint8_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        //static int8_t readBitsW(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint16_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        static int8_t readByte(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        //static int8_t readWord(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint16_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        static int8_t readBytes(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t length, uint8_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);
        //static int8_t readWords(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t length, uint16_t *data, uint16_t timeout=I2Cdev::readTimeout);

        static bool writeBit(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint8_t data);
        //static bool writeBitW(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitNum, uint16_t data);
        static bool writeBits(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint8_t data);
        //static bool writeBitsW(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t bitStart, uint8_t length, uint16_t data);
        static bool writeByte(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t data);
        static bool writeWord(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint16_t data);
        static bool writeBytes(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t length, uint8_t *data);
        static bool writeWords(uint8_t devAddr, uint8_t regAddr, uint8_t length, uint16_t *data);

        static uint16_t readTimeout;
};

#endif /* _I2CDEV_H_ */
```

Why am I getting this cpp error and how to fix?

### Edit

I have another header file being included which includes a struct, it might be formatted incorrectly? Here it is:

```
#ifndef _CALLIB_H_
#define _CALLIB_H_

//#include <Arduino.h>

#define CALLIB_DATA_VALID         0x15fc
#define CALLIB_DATA_VALID_LOW     0xfc // pattern to detect valid config - low byte
#define CALLIB_DATA_VALID_HIGH    0x15 // pattern to detect valid config - high byte

typedef struct
{
  short valid;                        // should contain the valid pattern if a good config
  bool magValid;                   // true if mag data valid
  short magMinX;                      // mag min x value
  short magMaxX;                      // mag max x value
  short magMinY;                      // mag min y value
  short magMaxY;                      // mag max y value
  short magMinZ;                      // mag min z value
  short magMaxZ;                      // mag max z value 
  bool accelValid;                 // true if accel data valid
  short accelMinX;                    // mag min x value
  short accelMaxX;                    // mag max x value
  short accelMinY;                    // mag min y value
  short accelMaxY;                    // mag max y value
  short accelMinZ;                    // mag min z value
  short accelMaxZ;                    // mag max z value
} CALLIB_DATA;

//  calLibErase() erases any current data in the EEPROM

void calLibErase();                

//  calLibWrite() writes new data to the EEPROM

void calLibWrite(CALLIB_DATA * calData); 

//  calLibRead() reads existing data and returns true if valid else false in not.

bool calLibRead(CALLIB_DATA * calData); 

#endif // _CALLIB_H_
```

Comment: in which line goes the error?

Comment: I put ** (line) ** around the error line, it's the class line.

Comment: Does your real file includes the final semicolon on the class definition? If so, please post the file that does `#include` your file `.h` file. (As it is here, the file compiles for me without any problem...)

Comment: Again, please, post at least everything until the `#include "i2cdev.h"` line in your `.cpp` file that is having compilation problems...

Answer (score 1):

The header file you included before this one is missing a semicolon on the final type definition:

```
struct S {
} s /* right here */
```

or perhaps

```
typedef struct
{
} S /* right here */
```

Everything in between is merely preprocessor commands, which doesn't affect the compiler parsing state.

The things "expected" in the error message are everything that can follow the identifier named in a typedef, or the identifier named in a variable declaration.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - is the error in this file? ALso I don't see this file including any others.

Comment: @JDS: Nope.  The error is caused by the code gotten when the preprocessor `#include` pastes together multiple files.  Whatever the compiler saw immediately before processing this file was missing something, something the compiler is still looking for.

Comment: How would you recommend I fix this then? EDIT - also I just realized that I have similar error in another .h file that defines a cpp class.

Comment: @JDS: You could use your compiler option to save preprocessed source code, and see what code came right before this.

Comment: I do have a struct in another header file that's being included in my project, but it looks correct.. I'll update the original answer now.